# How to apply a command to all the changed dependencies in GNU Make?

Tags: linux, build, makefile, gnu-make

Not sure what to google for this, so excuse me if the question is stupid.

I have a Makefile rule that depends on several files. When any of them changes, I want `make` to invoke a program and pass to it the list of the changed files as command line arguments. Ideally, I want something like this:

```
myfiles: file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
   my_command $(CHANGED_DEPENDENCIES)
```

For example, if I changed `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`, I'd expect `make` to invoke `my_command file1.txt file2.txt`

How do I accomplish that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an automatic variable:

> $?
>   The names of all the dependencies that are newer than the target, with spaces between them. For dependencies which are archive members, only the member named is used (see section Using make to Update Archive Files).

See [gnu make](http://theory.uwinnipeg.ca/localfiles/infofiles/make/make_98.html#SEC97)